# Make selenium No wait for element

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am using selenium for a while and have some question about the `IWebElement Wait` procedure.

We have the Explicit Wait and Implicit I use them and understand the meaning but..

How can I make selenium no wait for element at all?

I tried not to use wait functions but still when I call `FindElement` or `GoToUrl` its not always return immediately sometimes still wait for 0 to 60 sec

I noticed that in most of time the wait in `FindElement`  didn't return the element and wait for no reason.

for example: call for element id can take 3 sec and not immediately (lot off calls lot of time...)
maybe I am doing something wrong.

the main purpose is to take full control of the program and handle the wait time myself (for better efficiency)

maybe there are better articles to understand selenium architecture of finding elements ? (not the selenium API)

(I am using latest version of selenium 2.48.0)

Code example:

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0));
driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("someUrl");

IList<IWebElement> loginFrame = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("iframe"));
driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent().SwitchTo().Frame(loginFrame[0]);

driver.FindElement(By.Id("userID")).SendKeys("username");
driver.FindElement(By.Id("userPassword")).SendKeys("userPassword");
driver.FindElement(By.Id("login")).Click();

driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='something']/ul/li[2]/a")).Click();
driver.FindElement(By.PartialLinkText("someText")).Click(); // *
```

- At Last call its throw exception after something like 3 ~ 5 seconds and not immediately (When I set Implicit to 60 sec it's find the element!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by "how can I make selenium no wait for element at all? "

If you mean that you dont want selenium to wait at all for an element at all. I think this might work -

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
WebElement textbox = driver.findElement(By.id("textbox"));
```

Use this and write your own method which takes a locator and no of seconds to wait and then set the implicit wait inside the method depending on what has been passed to the method.

```
public WebElement locateElementById(int timeInSec, String id){
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(timeInSec, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id(id));
    return Element

}
```

Something like this. And then you can call it with the seconds you want.

when you want 0 seconds pass 0 when you want 10 seconds pass 10.

Comment: i used : driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0));

Comment: Hmm i think it should work .. Please try again and if it doesnt post your code.

Comment: I tried it but still when i call driver.FindElement(By.PartialLinkText("enter")).Click(); that function waits for couple of sec and throw exception what i want that it will throw the exception immediately and not waiting for 5 sec.. no element throw exception and let me handle it.

Comment: Post your relevant code. It should not wait at all  if nothing is set as timeout. Default value is 0.

Comment: driver.FindElement(By.PartialLinkText("someText")).Click(); 

This line is trying to find a element with some text so i believe there might be some processing and searching time required for this, as it is a very inefficient way to find an element. Can you try with a more definite locator like ID and see how much time it takes.

Comment: you right about that! i will try xpath (this element didn't have id or something unique that i can use) will do more test's with that, thank's

Comment: hmm Just to be sure that it is the case .. you fire the find element with any random ID which is not in your page. It should fail in less time , if it does fail in less than 4-5 secs, then you can assume that the wait time is because of searching the text.

Comment: What i mean is that FindElement should immediately search for that element in page source/DOM and not wait for the page/frames/elements to complete

Comment: And i think it is the default behaviour of selenium

Comment: i tested it and even if i have id its takes between 2 ~ 5 sec to respond (i understand that the webdriver RC need to look for that element in html source [i think DFS algorithm?]) can i do something about it ?...

Comment: Nothing that i know of. You can check out in IRC and ask the devs perhaps.